# ngIf (.) DOT notation scope inheritance doesn't work 2-ways in directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I couldn't get why this doesn't work. I thought dot-notation on ng-if makes the 2 way data binding but I could not change the parent $scope.modal.active within ng-if scope.

template/lupus/modal/modal.html:

```
<div class="lupus-modal">
    <img ng-src="{{lupusModalImg}}" class="img-responsive"/>
    <div ng-if="modal.active" class="backdrop modal-backdrop" ng-click="modal.active = false" > //this ng-click doesn't work as I expected
        <img ng-src="{{lupusModalImg}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

lupusModal directive:

```
.directive('lupusModal', [

function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            lupusModalImg: '='
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'template/lupus/modal/modal.html',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
            $scope.modal = {
                active: false,
                close: function () {
                    $scope.modal.active = false;
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            };

            $element.on('click', function () {
                $scope.modal.active = true; 
                $scope.$apply();
            });

        },
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, backdropCtrl) {
            //backdropCtrl.$element.$scope.slideElm[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        }
    };
}
]);
```

index.html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" lupus-modal lupus-modal-img="'img/certificates/UygunlukSertifikasi1.jpg'"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly, you are creating isolated scope in your directive, which does not inherit from its parent scope.

To use the `modal.active` set a two way binding using `=` in scope declaration in directive

```
         scope: {
            lupusModalImg: '=',
            modal:'='
        },
```

and declare your directive using

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" lupus-modal lupus-modal img="'img/certificates/UygunlukSertifikasi1.jpg'" modal='modal'></a>`